# How to force webpage scale down om mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

Everything looks ok until width reaches something around 370px. I need my page to somehow scale down. I use meta tags with viewport property set, but it does not help. I am a little bit lost in CSS properties, because everything I try seem to have no effect.

So, this is a link to codepen: https://codepen.io/garrrikkotua/pen/KKgdOOZ.

You can adjust editors console to see, how page's design changes according to width. Basically, all I need is to somehow "scale down" my page on small devices (now it is just cut).

```
<html lang="ru"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/email_website/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/static/email_website/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/static/email_website/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/static/email_website/site.webmanifest">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/subscribe_stylesheet.css">
    
    
    <title> Morningly | Подписаться</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="FullScreenLayout">
        <div class="LandingPage">
            <div class="LandingPageLeft">
                <img alt="morningly logo" src="/static/email_website/morningly_logo_small.png">
                <h3 class="main-h3">Новости прямо в ящик</h3>
                <p>Подпишитесь на Morningly - лучшее о бизнесе и технологиях за 5 минут и менее.
                </p>
                <div class="LandingPageSubscribe">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="T2HQwmDITQ1Vuq55wNhLjsZ7PC2IUG6FjHjSpggtiShHFkSk1xj1uDbC1HMUTjDN">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш Email" required="" id="id_email">
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Подписаться</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="LandingPageRight">
                <div class="phone-image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: why are you duplicating the same media query - `@media (min-width: 576px) {...}` ?

Comment: you also specified the rules `.LandingPage {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 0fr; height: 100vh; box-sizing: border-box; }` after media queries? You cannot do this, as the specified rules in the media query will be overridden.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, do you mean I should combine two media quieries for different classes in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the rules for the `.LandingPage` class after the `media queries`:

```
...
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
        min-height: 0vw;
    }
    .LandingPageRight {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

.LandingPage {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0fr;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
...
```

You can't do that. Because your rules in the media query will overlap.

And you have declared the `@media (max-width: 768px)` media query twice. One such rule is enough.

I set `grid-template-columns: 100%` for `.LandingPage`, and `width: 100%` for `input`, for `@media (max-width: 768px)`.

Was it necessary?

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.LandingPage {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0fr;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.LandingPageSubscribe {
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: rgb(242, 206, 0);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07) 0px 0.063em 0.313em 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0.438em 1.063em 0px;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

form {
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    background: rgb(242, 206, 0);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.15;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 500;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    border: none;
    min-height: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: none;
    overflow: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    object-fit: contain;
    align-self: start;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: none;
}

p {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.main-h3 {
    font-family: Poppins, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    color: rgb(242, 206, 0);
    margin-top: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

.phone-image {
    background: url("morningly_ready.png") center / contain no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.LandingPageRight {
    background-color: rgb(242, 206, 0);
    display: flex;
    width: 40vw;
}

.LandingPageLeft {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    padding: 0px 1rem;
    max-width: 700px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
        min-height: 0vw;
    }
    .LandingPageRight {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    
     .LandingPage {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
    }
    
        input {
        width: 100%;
}
    
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .LandingPageLeft {
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-left: 3rem;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
   
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/email_website/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/static/email_website/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/static/email_website/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/static/email_website/site.webmanifest">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/subscribe_stylesheet.css">
    
    
    <title> Morningly | Подписаться</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="FullScreenLayout">
        <div class="LandingPage">
            <div class="LandingPageLeft">
                <img alt="morningly logo" src="/static/email_website/morningly_logo_small.png">
                <h3 class="main-h3">Новости прямо в ящик</h3>
                <p>Подпишитесь на Morningly - лучшее о бизнесе и технологиях за 5 минут и менее.
                </p>
                <div class="LandingPageSubscribe">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="T2HQwmDITQ1Vuq55wNhLjsZ7PC2IUG6FjHjSpggtiShHFkSk1xj1uDbC1HMUTjDN">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш Email" required="" id="id_email">
                        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Подписаться</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="LandingPageRight">
                <div class="phone-image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: If you have any questions, you can tell me about them. Always happy to help.